# How to define the input parameter in oracle which is being called from java servlet

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, plsql

I have a stored procedure which has two input parameters and two output parameters. this procedure is being called from the java servlet. I want to send the input parameter as a collection through servlet to the procedure. This input collection consists of three string varibles. How should i create the input parameter in oracle for this. I am getting the error fail to convert to internal representation error for the below code

Below is the code of java

```
String[] collectData = new String[3]; 
collectData[0]=request.getParameter("name"); 
collectData[1]=request.getParameter("area"); 
collectData[2]=request.getParameter("subject"); 

ArrayDescriptor inputData = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("T_INPUT_DATA",con); 

ARRAY inputCollection = new ARRAY (inputData, con, collectData);

String SQL = "{call student_api.p_chk_data (?,?,?,?)}"; 
cstmt = con.prepareCall (SQL); cstmt.setString(1, sId); 
cstmt.setObject(2, inputCollection);
```

Oracle Code

```
create or replace type input_data as object(

user_name varchar2(50),
password varchar2(50),
confirm_password varchar2(50)

)
create or replace type t_input_data as input_data;

procedure p_chk_data(
 student_id IN varchar2,
 in_collection in t_input_data,
 out_error_code out number, 
 out_error_message out varchar2)
```

Comment: Below is the code of java servlet and oracle collectionsString[] collectData = new String[3];
   collectData[0]=request.getParameter("name");
   collectData[1]=request.getParameter("area");
   collectData[2]=request.getParameter("subject");                 ArrayDescriptor inputData =
ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("T_INPUT_DATA",con);
     ARRAY inputCollection = new ARRAY (inputData,   con, collectData);String SQL = "{call student_api.p_chk_data (?,?,?,?)}";
      cstmt = con.prepareCall (SQL);
      cstmt.setString(1, sId);
      cstmt.setObject(2, inputCollection);

Comment: ORacle code   create or replace type input_data as object(
name varchar2(50),
area varchar2(50),
subject varchar2(50)
)
create or replace type t_input_data as input_data;

Comment: Please don't use comments to post additional information; use the `Edit` link to edit your question and add the code example there.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using *oracle.sql.StructDescriptor* and *oracle.sql.STRUCT*

```
StructDescriptor structdesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor  
                                    (sql_type_name, connection);
```

Then initialize it using:

```
STRUCT myStruct = new STRUCT (structdesc, con, collectData);
```

And finally set myStruct in the callable parameter:

```
cstmt.setObject(2, myStruct);
```

Comment: Thanks maverik..!! However now i am getting an error of Fail to construct descriptor: Invalid arguments. Any idea about this..?

Comment: On which line?     StructDescriptor structdesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor  
                                    ("T_INPUT_DATA", connection);